# What data structure is used in apps for modifiable lists?

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist, time-complexity

In some apps you have lists of items where you can move items around, delete items, add or insert items, etc.

Normally I'd say an ArrayList would work but apparently a lot of operations are linear time.

Is there a better data structure most people use for this?

Comment: You can use a linked list but then you lose random access.

Comment: What do people use in practice, because they seem to do both?

Comment: I'm not sure. But how big is your dataset? If it's small enough to be displayed, moving objects around in `ArrayList` should be fast enough to go unnoticed.

Comment: So I guess most people take the performance hit due to small n? What about large n like a million?

Comment: Probably using an index since it's too big to fit in memory.

Comment: What do you mean? Well what about 10000? Something where it may matter and also fit in memory

Comment: `LinkedList` and `ArrayList` have their own advantages and disadvantages, decide on what your main use cases are and choose the implementation that suits those uses cases better.

Comment: That's what I'm asking though. Based on the operations I've mentioned, what do people use?

Comment: @SeanHill (a) Are you trying to maintain an order to the elements? Keeping them in order or not caring about order is crucial, each way leads to different solutions. (b) Do you care about preventing duplicate entries, or do you want to allow duplicates (meaning adding a dup does not replace the original)?

Comment: @BasilBourque I want to allow people to be able to reorganize elements as they wish; order does matter in that context. Duplicates are OK. For instance maybe someone wants to brush their teeth, eat, then brush again -- brushing might be considered a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your priority is inserting and/or removing elements from a collection that maintains an arbitrary order, the the [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) class bundled with Java meets that need. You can very quickly insert or remove any element at any specific index number.

Each link in the chain that is a doubly-linked-list knows its predecessor and its successor. Each element holds a reference/pointer to the element in front and another reference/pointer to the one following. So insertion means telling a linked pair to consider the new element as their successor or predecessor. The rest of the chain remains untouched.

The downside to `LinkedList` is that access by index number is expensive as finding the nth element means traversing n links going from one element to the next in the chain. A linked-list inherently means sequential access. So, getting to an element is expensive but once there the mechanics of the insertion/deletion is cheap.

Another downside to `LinkedList` is searching, for similar reason (sequential access). Since the ordering is arbitrary and not sorted, there is no way to approximately predict/expect where the element might be found. So searching means traversing the chain from one element to the next and performing a comparison on each one.

On the other hand, if indexed access is your priority, then `ArrayList` is the way to go. Directly accessing the nth element is the speciality for `ArrayList`.  Inserting and removing elements are very expensive operations requiring the backing array to be rebuilt unless dealing with the last element. For large arrays this has implications for memory management as the array must be in contiguous memory.

Both `LinkedList` and `ArrayList` allow duplicates.

Neither `LinkedList` nor `ArrayList` are thread-safe. So if accessing either from more than one thread, you have a whole other category of concerns to address.

To understand the nuances, study [linked lists](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) and [arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure)  in general.

Comment: Linked list sounds terrible, why bother with fast inserts and removals if access has to be done from the start each time in linear time? When is this preferable? When you're not accessing elements often?

Comment: @SeanHill Rather than converse here, read the Wikipedia pages I linked in my last sentence to learn about the mechanics involved. The purpose of a linked list is cheap insertion/deletion in an arbitrarily-ordered collection, using little memory and fast execution to execute the addition/removal. You also get cheap traversal along the chain. In a doubly-linked list you also get cheap traversal along the chain in the reverse direction (backwards). Computers are not magic; like engineering, programming is **all about trade-offs** between costs and benefits according to your needs.